# Flutter Carousel Slider

Tags: flutter

I couldn't find a right way to make the carousel slide. anyone who know please share.

I tried to create with row and many widgets but didn't work.

if anyone know how to create carousel slide with the same card details in flutter, please share the code. [image: Please check the [image][1]]
Thanks

Comment: Check [Top Flutter Carousel or Cover Flow packages](https://fluttergems.dev/carousel-cover-flow/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?
https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_carousel
This package has a `.builder` where you could return a custom widget

If you just want a horizontal scrollable list of widgets, you can use a singleChildScrollView. Use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` to change the scroll direction. Set the child to a Row filled with images.

You could also use a ListView with the same `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`

Which one is better sort of depends what the list is made of, how you want to interact with it, and how many items